# CSS Positioning

Tags: css, position

I´v a problem on the site [PSR](http://psr.mediameans.de)

how can I make it that the Footer always under the content div automaticaly

The Content and the Footer are relative positioned.

**Another Question: How can i make the Footer the same size as the header_bg ? –**

Comment: Your site 404s. Please edit your post with the correct URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing the footer down the same as the content will help.

```
top:541px;
```

I assume all those empty `p` tags are to push the footer down, try deleting those and implementing this CSS.

Comment: Another Question: How can i make the Footer the same size as the header_bg ?

Comment: Look at the height of the header, then apply the css style `height:numberpx;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Comment: hey tom will this help for your second question   #header {
    width: 959px;
    height: 169px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background: url(header.jpg);
}

Comment: can explain your second question? what are you trying exactly?

Comment: Ok, 
the header bg and the footer bg should be wide as the window width

Comment: try setting width to 100% and the height to 100%